# "Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <img> in <a>." - How to use MagicZoom Plus in a server side app? -

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, magiczoomplus

How to use MagicZoom Plus in a server-side app like next js?

I see the following error when I refresh the page:

***"Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in ."***

[image]

```
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);

  <div>
   <a href={item.src[activeIndex]} className="MagicZoom">
    <img src={item.src[activeIndex]} alt="" />
   </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Looks like a hydration issue, where server HTML doesn't match client one. Could you provide the code that is triggering the warning?

Comment: Please see the updated comment above @juliomalves, how can I remove that hydration issue?

Comment: Is that the full code for that component? If not, could you post the rest?

Comment: Sure, it's in this repo, https://github.com/AndresHMosqueda/productnextJs @juliomalves